# using of two way hash in data compression

Tags: function, hash, compression, two-way

Is it possible to use two way hash function in data compression. If so which type of hash function is suitable.(If we can use hash function for compression we can send for example 1GByte(data) as only 1Kbyte (hash) so we can improve bandwidth and save storage .If it is possible receiver can restore  data from hash . Consider that this days Computers & receiver have very fast processors  .

Answer (score 1):

No.  (That answer is completely and totally sufficient, but I have added this sentence to meet SO's minimum answer length.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, until now there is No two-way hash.

Comment: @Eric Aya, No it is did not mentioned. Mark Adler answer is not clear for beginners. most begineers will understand from his answer that 2-way hash cannot compress the information and that is not correct. 2-way hash will compress the information but  until now there is No two-way hash 